# MethodNotAllowedHttpException while submitting form to process using laravel?

Tags: php, forms, laravel-5

I am new to laravel and trying to create a simple application that is blog, i wanted to store a post details into database. i have setup my database and tables also using laravel commands.
i have created a following form in order to store the data into database :

```
@extends('main')

@section('title','| Create Post')
@endsection

@section('content')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <h1>Create New Post</h1>
        <hr/>
        <form action="store" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label name="title">Title:</label>
                    <input id="title" name="title" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label name="body">Post Body:</label>
                    <textarea id="body" name="body" class="form-control"></textarea>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" value="Save Post">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

i have create a route rule for this form submit request as follows :

```
 Route::resource('posts','PostController');
```

where PostController is controller where all required resource method is implemented for processing and saving data as

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use App\Post;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostController extends Controller {

public function index()
{
    //
}

public function create()
{
    return view('posts.create');
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    //validate the data
    $this->validate($request,array(
        'title' => 'required|max:255',
        'body' => 'required'
    ));

    //store in the database
    $post = new Post;
    $post->title = $request->title;
    $post->body = $request->body;
    $post->save();

    //redirect to page
    return redirect()->route('posts.show',$post->id);
}

public function show($id)
{
    //
}

public function edit($id)
{
    //
}

public function update($id)
{
    //
}

public function destroy($id)
{
    //
}

}
```

i have also list down my route using command prompt which gives me following output :

App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@getIndex              |            |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | posts                                                 | posts.index   | App\Http\Controllers\PostController@index                  |            |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | posts/create                                          | posts.create  | App\Http\Controllers\PostController@create                 |            |
|        | POST                           | posts                                                 | posts.store   | App\Http\Controllers\PostController@store                  |            |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | posts/{posts}                                         | posts.show    | App\Http\Controllers\PostController@show                   |            |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | posts/{posts}/edit                                    | posts.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\PostController@edit                   |            |
|        | PUT                            | posts/{posts}                                         | posts.update  | App\Http\Controllers\PostController@update                 |            |
|        | PATCH                          | posts/{posts}                                         |               | App\Http\Controllers\PostController@update                 |            |
|        | DELETE                         | posts/{posts}                                         | posts.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\PostController@destroy

i am getting MethodNotAllowedHttpException after submitting the form for saving the details.

Comment: Your output tells me that your ```create``` method accepts ```POST``` where the store method expects ```GET```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@section('content')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <h1>Create New Post</h1>
        <hr/>
        <form action="{{ route('posts.store') }}" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label name="title">Title:</label>
                    <input id="title" name="title" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label name="body">Post Body:</label>
                    <textarea id="body" name="body" class="form-control"></textarea>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" value="Save Post">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#resource-controllers)